# Creating an image from a usercontrol

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a custom live tile for a WP8.1 winrt app.  How do I go about creating an image from a user control for the live tile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) will render a UIElement from the visual tree into a bitmap. You can call RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(userControl1,width,height) to generate an image of the control and then use a BitmapEncoder to save it out to a file.

Comment: I keep getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range." when trying the RenderAsync.  Any idea what could be causing that? I'm just doing:

RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(userControl, 159, 159);

Comment: Does the usercontrol need to be displayed on the screen to use renderasync? Is there a way to do this without doing so?

Comment: It doesn't need to be displayed, but it needs to be in the visual tree. It can be hidden behind another control or such.